# Building esp8266 developement environment w/ Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, esp8266

I am trying to build a development environment for my esp8266 in Ubuntu.

I am instructed to enter this command:

```
make STANDALONE=y
```

This is the output:

> make -C crosstool-NG -f ../Makefile _ct-ng make[1]: Entering directory
>   '/home/william/esp8266/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG' ./bootstrap Running
>   autoconf... ./bootstrap: 5: ./bootstrap: autoconf: not found
>   ../Makefile:295: recipe for target '_ct-ng' failed make[1]: ***
>   [_ct-ng] Error 127 make[1]: Leaving directory
>   '/home/william/esp8266/esp-open-sdk/crosstool-NG' Makefile:292: recipe
>   for target 'crosstool-NG/ct-ng' failed make: *** [crosstool-NG/ct-ng]
>   Error 2

I have built my Virtualbox. I don't know what this output means.

Answer (score 0):

If you really really want to set up your own build environment I suggest you follow http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=toolchain#how_to_setup_a_vm_to_host_your_toolchain. Unfortunately, it's too long to quote here.

What you can try is the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

Allow me to suggest two alternative approaches that address your "is there an easier way" question. I'm *assuming* you want to work with the NodeMCU firmware.:

- use the NodeMCU custom build service at http://nodemcu-build.com/
- use Docker and a VM to do the heavy (build) lifting: https://hub.docker.com/r/marcelstoer/nodemcu-build/

Disclaimer: both were created and are maintained by yours truly.

Comment: I am looking for the cleanest solution. As you know the esp8266's limiting factor is memory. I want to use basic AVR Assembler to write source code because of memory limits, execution time, heat, etc. I have the tools I just need to know the best platform to write and translate this source code into object code. NodeMCU based on python? I have watched 20 hours of tutorials on writing machine code, I have the specs., the AVR Assemblers User Guide and the 8-bit AVR Instruction set. I just need to know the best platform.....shell....environment....whatever!!! to get started. THX 4 ur help.

Comment: You question is highly subjective. For me the most painless platform is NodeMCU. You can program in Lua, an event driven asynchronous scripting language that's been around for 20+ years. http://nodemcu-build.com/ allows you to build a firmware that only contains those modules which you actually need - no more memory issues. Furthermore, for ease of use I suggest you work with a dev kit that can be hooked up to your computer directly with a standard USB cord rather than fiddling with 5V -> 3.3V converters on a breadboard: http://wp.me/pzoQb-sk.

Comment: @BillyReuben ; with one of my projects, I also had similar concerns. I tried nodeMCU, ArduinoIDE, Native SDK. For some of my apps (which timing and memory is a concern) i prefer to use native sdk. But mostly nodeMCU is enough. For example if you want to create a web server, it will take much less time to develop with nodemcu. I did not want to use ArduinoIDE becuse underlying platform is different. And this nodemcu custom build tool is wonderful. Thanks to who created it.

Comment: "this nodemcu custom build tool is wonderful" - good to hear, you're welcome.

Comment: Thank you, all, for your help. This will, definitely, guide me to the righteous path. This link: wp.me/pzoQb-sk clears up much of my confusion concerning the lingo of this craft. Although these units are relatively inexpensive, the cost of an error in ordering the wrong hardware is measured in units of time, not currency. It is no surprise Mr. Gerwin Janssen lives in Shenzhen.....he tired of waiting for his package to arrive and just move to the source??????? Hope your solstice was pleasant, the weather here is crazy......record high temperatures. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Glad to help. I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/257994.